# Can't figure out how to separate away player and home player when joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have **two tables**, one is a `schedules` table and the other is a `stats` table for quarterbacks.

I have joined them like so..

```
    SELECT statsSchedules.*
           , awayTeam.fullName     awayQBName
           , awayTeam.passComp     awayPlayerPassComp
           , awayTeam.passAtt      awayPlayerPassAtt
           , awayTeam.passCompPct  awayPlayerPassCompPct
           , awayTeam.passYds        awayPassYds
           , awayTeam.passInts     awayPlayerPassInts
           , awayTeam.passLongest  awayPlayerLongestPass
           , awayTeam.passPts        awayPlayerPassPts
           , awayTeam.passerRating awayPlayerPassRating
           , awayTeam.passSacks    awayQBTimesSacked
           , awayTeam.passTDs        awayQBTds
           , awayTeam.statId       awayStatId

           , homeTeam.fullName     homeQBName
           , homeTeam.passComp     homePlayerPassComp
           , homeTeam.passAtt      homePlayerPassAtt
           , homeTeam.passCompPct  homePlayerPassCompPct
           , homeTeam.passYds        homePassYds
           , homeTeam.passInts     homePlayerPassInts
           , homeTeam.passLongest  homePlayerLongestPass
           , homeTeam.passPts        homePlayerPassPts
           , homeTeam.passerRating homePlayerPassRating
           , homeTeam.passSacks    homeQBTimesSacked
           , homeTeam.passTDs        homeQBTds
           , homeTeam.statId        homeStatId

      FROM statsSchedules
    INNER JOIN statsPassing AS awayTeam
        ON statsSchedules.scheduleId =  awayTeam.scheduleId
    INNER JOIN statsPassing AS homeTeam
        ON statsSchedules.scheduleId =  homeTeam.scheduleId
     WHERE statsSchedules.scheduleId=542769239
     ORDER BY statsSchedules.weekIndex ASC
```

Doing that is resulting in multiple repeats of stats and names.

[image: What my SQL query returns]

I have tried using `SELECT DISTINCT statsSchedules.*` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. (Most people here want formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Simplify your question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: This won't work that way. You have no logic in there to ensure that the join on statsPassing doesn't pull up both teams for homeTeam and awayTeam

Comment: ok how do I add logic to ensure that the join on `statsPassing` doesn't pull up both teams for `homeTeam` and `awayTeam`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue thanks to the comment from [user3532232](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3532232/user3532232)

I was close, what I needed was to add

```
    AND statsSchedules.awayTeamId=awayTeam.teamId
    AND statsSchedules.scheduleId=awayTeam.scheduleId
```

plus

```
    AND statsSchedules.homeTeamId=homeTeam.teamId 
    AND statsSchedules.scheduleId=homeTeam.scheduleId
```

After adding those two `AND` functions the query shows the correct player(s) in the `awayTeam` and in the `homeTeam` columns without repetition.

Answer (score 0):

you need to join the statsPassing on match and team also(I'd guess since you're not saying what you want). eg.:

```
select *--the stats you need
FROM statsSchedules
JOIN statsPassing AS awayTeam ON statsSchedules.scheduleId=awayTeam.scheduleId and statsSchedules.awayTeamID=awayTeam.teamID
JOIN statsPassing AS homeTeamON statsSchedules.scheduleId=homeTeam.scheduleId and statsSchedules.homeTeamID=homeTeamTeam.teamID
WHERE statsSchedules.scheduleId=542769239
ORDER BY statsSchedules.weekIndex ASC
```

Comment: Yes this is a specific match. the `WHERE statsSchedules.scheduleId=542769239` specifies that match. I'm a bit confused by your code. In the part you have `and statsSchedules.distinctMatch` is that the part you guessed?

Comment: updated my answer. And yes the distinctMatch part i guessed

Comment: What does the `FROM statsSchedules as t1` do? when I put that in the query, I get the following error #1051 - Unknown table 'statsSchedules' just curious as it works without it.

Comment: sry, a typo from my part. Its just a alias for the table statsSchedules in the current selectCase. Just like you've renamed statsPassing to awayTeam and homeTeam.